# Filtering results in two tables

Tags: mysql, filtering, inner-join, create-table

I'm porting an invoice system with delivery notes that was on msSQL and VB2008 to PHP + MySQL, I've finished everything except when I'm going to make an invoice for a customer.

I'm using these tables:

Table 1 is where I add each delivery note

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `delivery_note` (
  `id_delivery_note` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `number_delivery_note` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_product` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `qty_delivered` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `qty_received` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `client_code` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `active` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_invoice` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `invoiced` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_delivery_note`)
) TYPE=MyISAM  ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC AUTO_INCREMENT=6 ;


INSERT INTO `delivery_note` (`id_delivery_note`, `number_delivery_note`, `id_product`, `qty_delivered`, `qty_received`, `date`, `client_code`, `active`, `id_invoice`, `invoiced`) VALUES
(2, 2, 13, 1, NULL, '2012-04-25', '1', 1, NULL, 0),
(3, 3, 24, 1, NULL, '2012-04-25', '1', 1, NULL, 0),
(5, 1, 13, 2, NULL, '2012-04-24', '2', 1, NULL, 0);
```

Table 2 is where I keep the prices for each customer, for each item (All the customers have different prices)

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `product_price` (
  `id_product_price` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `client_code` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_product` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `price` decimal(15,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_product_price`)
) TYPE=MyISAM  ROW_FORMAT=FIXED AUTO_INCREMENT=6 ;


INSERT INTO `product_price` (`id_product_price`, `client_code`, `id_product`, `price`) VALUES
(1, 1, 13, 1.51),
(2, 1, 24, 43.11),
(3, 1, 24, 11.00),
(4, 2, 13, 1.52),
(5, 2, 24, 43.12);
```

And the query I've been using is:

```
SELECT number_delivery_note, delivery_note.id_product, qty_delivered, date, product_price.price
FROM delivery_note, product_price
WHERE(delivery_note.client_code = 1) AND (delivery_note.invoiced = 0)
```

And gives me all this:

http://s14.postimage.org/rghvfmo9t/Sin_t_tulo_1.gif

When I need only this data:

http://s15.postimage.org/8hnpv9qt7/propblema.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/65c79/7) is probably what you want:

```
SELECT id_delivery_note, number_delivery_note, date, x.id_product, x.price,
qty_delivered FROM delivery_note d INNER JOIN product_price x
ON x.id_product = d.id_product
AND d.client_code = x.client_code WHERE d.client_code = 1 and d.invoiced = 0
GROUP BY id_product
```

Comment: THIS is exactly what I needed! I think I wouldn't figure it out by myself if you didn't help me with this, You've inspired me to improve my basic MySQL skills, thank you! :)

Comment: @Mario: The way this site works you are encouraged to accept an answer when it has solved your question. There is a checkmark next to this answer you should click if you wish to do that. I'm glad it helped.

Comment: Thank you! I'll also read the FAQ to see how this site works and help others :)

Answer (score 0):

You could 'group by' the first 3 fields.

Comment: I tried it, but it messes up with the price, but thanks a lot for your comment :)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT number_delivery_note, delivery_note.id_product, 
       qty_delivered, date, product_price.price
FROM   delivery_note, product_price
WHERE (delivery_note.client_code = 1) AND 
      (delivery_note.invoiced = 0) and
       delivery_note.id_product = product_price.id_product
```

but why is

```
3        1          24        11.00
```

not included in table `product_price`?

Comment: 3  1  24  11.00 <- Is another price assigned to client "1" but still hasn't a delivery note to make an invoice. Thanks for your participation :)